# Are there any other open-source libraries for QR code reading in Python

Tags: python, qr-code

Reading QR code in python using qrtools is unreliable, works only for few QR codes. Are there any other open-source libraries for QR code reading in Python?
Please help

Comment: Sorry but asking for library recommendations is off-topic on SO for the following reason: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: Can check out https://github.com/oostendo/python-zxing.